# Issue about Return type of generic method

Tags: java, generic-collections

I have a problem editing my first generic method. This is my method:

```
    public <T> void validate(Class <T> clazz, Object model, String modelInstanceName, BindingResult result){
    .....
    }
```

It works.

Now, my problem is that the method "validate" must return a `FieldError` type. I tried editing it, following some posts read here, but I still keep on getting errors.

I tried something like this:

```
public <T> FieldError validate(Class <T> clazz, Object model, String modelInstanceName, BindingResult result){
    .....
    FieldError fieldError =  new FieldError(......);
    return fieldError;
}
```

But I still get the error:  `This method must return a result of type FieldError`

Thank you

Comment: Your current return type is `void`. Just replace it with `FieldError`. Or am I missing something? I don't quite get what the problem is, sorry...

Comment: I thought that what I needed was just add "FieldError" as return type in the method signature, but I still get the error  above. I edited my post

Comment: That is absolutely correct. And the updated code you posted should work as it stands. Are you sure you don't have a branch somewhere (if/then/else/for/while/...) where you `return;` without returning a `FieldError`?

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali, you're change should not produce that error.  Are you certain that's the line it's (still) complaining about?

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code (and removed the ellipses) and it works fine.  No idea why you're getting an error.

Comment: I'm an idiot! I didn't see a "}". My "return" was inside a "while". Sorry guys for made you wasting your time. Thanks everybody :)